# Finding embeded document in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My collection is like this

```
{
  "name":""
  "type":""
  "arr":[
   {
     "type":""
     "other field"
     ...
   },
  {
     "type":""
     "other field"
     ...
   }
}
```

and my condition is
  input parameter is name.
so based on name i have to fetch document and one more condition is that type outside and inside the array should match..
Need to fetch those records alone..
How to achieve this

Comment: I think you will need to use two queries for that.

Comment: yeah. But without that is there any option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad performance, but just work (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where)

```
db.SOME_COLLECTION.find({
  name:'SOME_VALUE', 
  $where: 
    function() {
      for(var i = 0; i < obj.arr.length; i++) {
        if(obj.arr[i].type==obj.type) {
          return obj
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

p.s. aggregation framework has solved analogical problems, but in this case, imho, only $where clause available

Comment: @khurrum qureshi - the main problem in comparing values in field1 and field2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is how you get the desired result

```
{name:"",type:"",arr.type:""}
```

you can put the desired values and it will return you all the matching record.