# Query all documents and sub-documents for a specific key in mongodb without looping

Tags: json, mongodb

I had hard time choosing the right title for this question. I have a list of documents and sub-documents as the following

```
{
        "name" : "Pets",
        "subcategories" : [
            {
                "name" : "Cats",
                "fbCategories" : []
            },
            {
                "name" : "Dogs",
                "fbCategories" : []
            }
        ],
        "fbCategories" : ["Pet Services","Pet Supplies", "Animal"]
    },
    {
        "name" : "Entertainment",
        "subcategories" : [
            {
                "name" : "Music",
                "subcategories" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "Albums",
                        "fbCategories" : [ "Album"]
                    },
                    {
                        "name" : "Musicians",
                        "fbCategories" : ["Concert Tour","Musician/Band"]
                    }
                ],
                "fbCategories" : [
                    "Concert Venue",
                    "Music Chart",
                    "Music Video",
                    "Musical Instrument",
                    "Record Label",
                    "Music"
                ]
            }
```

In this example, we have two main categories ***("Pets","Entertainment" )*** and their corresponding subcategories *(cats and dogs for "Pets",... )*. Although there are different levels of subcategories, but all documents/sub-documents have two keys, **name and fbCategories**. I want to find the fbCategories for each category/subcategory without writing a loop or multiple queries. Is there anyway to query them all within one query, the result should list the *"fbCategories"* for each  *"name"* key. For example for *"musicians"*  , it will list `["Concert Tour","Musician/Band"]` , while for *"Music"* it will list

```
 ["Concert Venue","Music Chart","Music Video","Musical Instrument","Record Label","Music"]
```

Comment: If the subcategories are at different and unknown depths, then no, not efficiently, there is not. Ideally, you'd want to index the `name` field, but you wouldn't want to have lots of indexes based on the level of dot notation that could be required (and there's a practical (~16) and hard limit (64) on the # of indexes per collection). Can you flatten the structure out (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#data-modeling-decisions)?

Answer (score 0):

just look at: [Finding embeded document in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100210/finding-embeded-document-in-mongodb/16103703#16103703)

without loop, imho, this problems has not solution, because $where statement restricted in aggregation framework.