# matching fields internally in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having following document in mongodb

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("517b88decd483543a8bdd95b"),
        "studentId" : 23,
        "students" : [
          {
           "id" : 23,
           "class" : "a"
           },
          {
           "id" : 55,
           "class" : "b"
           }
        ]
     }
     {
        "_id" : ObjectId("517b9d05254e385a07fc4e71"),
        "studentId" : 55,
        "students" : [
           {
            "id" : 33,
            "class" : "c"
          }
         ]
     }
```

`Note:` Not an actual data but schema is exactly same.

`Requirement:` Finding the document which matches the `studentId` and `students.id`(id inside the students array using **single query**.

I have tried the code like below

```
db.data.aggregate({$match:{"students.id":"$studentId"}},{$group:{_id:"$student"}});
```

`Result:` Empty Array, If i replace {"students.id":"$studentId"} to {"students.id":33} it is returning the second document in the above shown json.

Is it possible to get the documents for this scenario using single query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If possible, I'd suggest that you set the condition while storing the data so that you can do a quick truth check (`isInStudentsList`). It would be super fast to do that type of query.

Otherwise, there is a relatively complex way of using the Aggregation framework pipeline to do what you want in a single query:

```
db.students.aggregate( 
    {$project: 
        {studentId: 1, studentIdComp: "$students.id"}},  
    {$unwind: "$studentIdComp"}, 
    {$project : { studentId : 1, 
        isStudentEqual: { $eq : [ "$studentId", "$studentIdComp" ] }}}, 
    {$match: {isStudentEqual: true}})
```

Given your input example the output would be:

```
{
    "result" : [
         {
             "_id" : ObjectId("517b88decd483543a8bdd95b"),
             "studentId" : 23,
             "isStudentEqual" : true
         }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

A brief explanation of the steps:

1. Build a projection of the document with just `studentId` and a new field with an array containing just the `id` (so the first document it would contain `[23, 55]`.
2. Using that structure, [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/). That creates a new temporary document for each array element in the `studentIdComp` array.
3. Now, take those documents, and create a new document projection, which continues to have the `studentId` and adds a new field called `isStudentEqual` that compares the equality of two fields, the `studentId` and `studentIdComp`. Remember that at this point there is a single temporary document that contains those two fields.
4. Finally, check that the comparison value `isStudentEqual` is true and return those documents (which will contain the original document `_id` and the `studentId`.
5. If the student was in the list multiple times, you might need to group the results on `studentId` or `_id` to prevent duplicates (but I don't know that you'd need that).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's impossible ;(

to solve this problem it is necessary to use a **$where** statement 
(example: [Finding embeded document in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100210/finding-embeded-document-in-mongodb)),

but **$where** is *restricted* from being used with aggregation framework

Comment: note that $where is not necessary with Aggregation framework though (as WiredPrairie's answer shows you can use $project to create new field and then use $match)

Comment: exactly @AsyaKamsky, but in many questions, i  observe classical situation:  compare one filed and another field in some hierarchy. i know, that problem generally in a bad data model. many devs create data storage model just directly copy+paste from relational storages ;)

Comment: well, to be fair, sometimes requirements evolve and evolving schema along with it means understanding the new requirements first.  This sort of workaround can be an intermediate step while understanding what needs to be added to schema in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

`db.data.find({students: {$elemMatch: {id:  23}} , studentId: 23});`

Comment: I believe the question is how to find all documents where the condition is true (select document where students list contains studentId.)